# GitBashへのパスを指定してもIntelliJ IDEAからBashスクリプトが実行できません（「式またはステートメントのトークン」エラー）

Tags: windows, bash, intellij-idea, git-bash

BashスクリプトをWindows／IntelliJ IDEAから実行したいと思います。
BashはWindowsの一部分ではないと知ってはいますが、Gitがあり、これにBashが付いています。
このBashへのパスを明示的に指示します（常に「C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe」）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記のボタン

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

で実行しますと、

```
発生場所 行:1 文字:37
+ ... n\bash.exe" "D:/IntelliJ IDEA/InHouseDevelopment/XXX/ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
式またはステートメントのトークン '"D:/IntelliJ IDEA/InHouseDevelopment/XXX/NNN/test.bash"' を使用できません。
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

というエラーが発生します。

原因を教えていただけますでしょうか。

メッセージと論理だけ判断すると、原因はファイル内ではなく、生成されるコマンドにあります。

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" "D:/IntelliJ IDEA/XXX/NNN/test.bash"
```

`"D:/IntelliJ IDEA/XXX/NNN/test.bash"`文字列に下記が良くないでしょうか。

Comment: コマンドプロンプト？ から bash起動できますか？(プロンプトが出て `ls` とか実行できるはず) 起動できるなら, 「生成されるコマンド」を試してみるとなにか分かるかも

Comment: @oriri 「コマンドプロンプト？ から bash起動できますか」違います。IntelliJ IDEAですから、コマンドプロンプトを直接使わずに実行したいと思います。上記のコマンドは、IntelliJ IDEAに生成されたのです。

Comment: 「bash起動できますか？」とは動作確認できていますか？という意味です。コマンド窓から一通り手操作で行ってみて, 動くかどうか, エラーならどんなエラーになってるか確認してみてはどうか？という意味です

Comment: `Git for Windows`のインストール時に`Adjusting your PATH environment`の画面で一番下の`Use Git and optional Unix tools from the Command Prompt`を選んだかどうかで変わるかもしれませんね。[私家版 Git For Windowsのインストール手順](https://opcdiary.net/technical/programming/%E7%A7%81%E5%AE%B6%E7%89%88-git-for-windows%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86/) あと`Select Components`の画面で`Associate .sh files to be run with Bash`のチェックをデフォルトのまま外していなければ、起動プログラムにbash.exeを指定せずとも拡張子を`.sh`にしたスクリプトを指定するだけで実行できるかもしれません。

Comment: 一つ前の拡張子`.sh`に関して[Windows のファイル拡張子の関連付け](https://qiita.com/TsuneoNakanishi/items/5f0248c82bf073cf2868)の方法で調べたら、`Adjusting your PATH environment`の画面で変更せず一番下を選ばなかった環境では、`assoc .sh`が`.sh=sh_auto_file`、`ftype sh_auto_file`が`sh_auto_file="C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --no-cd "%L" %*`となっていたので、起動するプログラムパスやパラメータをそれに合わせて試してみるのが良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

出力を見る限り、IntelliJ から PowerShell が実行され、PowerShell 上でコマンド実行が失敗しています。

PowerShell では実行するコマンドをフルパスで表記してクォートした場合、そのままだと文字列リテラルとして扱われてしまいコマンド実行と解釈されません。このため 2 つ目の引数が引数と解釈されずに UnexpectedToken エラーとなっています。

これを回避するには、[call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) にクォートした文字列を渡してあげる方法があります。

```
& "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" "D:/Path/to/test.bash"
```

また PowerShell ではバックティック `` ` `` で空白をエスケープできるので、以下でも実行できます。

```
C:\Program` Files\Git\bin\bash.exe "D:/Path/to/test.bash"
```

参考: Learn/PowerShell/about_Parsing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2

IntelliJ からこのどちらかが実行されるように設定すると良いでしょう。

また、cmd.exe であればクォートした文字列のままでコマンドとして認識されるので、困らないのであれば IntelliJ のデフォルトのシェルを cmd.exe に変更するという方法もあります: https://pleiades.io/help/idea/settings-tools-terminal.html

※ところで Windows 11 であれば WSL 2 が利用できるので、わざわざ Git Bash を使わなくても良いかもしれません。